# SQL Query to check if 40 columns in table is null 

Tags: sql

How do I select few columns in a table that only contain NULL values for all the rows? 
Suppose if Table has 100 columns, among this 100 columns 60 columns has null values.
How can I write where condition to check if 60 columns are null.

Comment: python, c#, and ruby?  Could you help out by supplying the database you're using?

Comment: You mean where these columns are null for all rows? 40 or 60? Which database?

Comment: I don't understand the question. You want to know for a certain columns if there is at least one null value in all the rows? Or if all the values are null? Or do you confuse rows with columns?

Answer (score 29):

maybe with a COALESCE

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE coalesce(col1, col2, col3, ..., colN) IS NULL
```

Comment: If there's any chance to use an index on any of these fields, you've killed it by putting a function around it.

Comment: Yeah, per-row functions are a performance killer on any decent-sized table.

Comment: coalesce only works when all those columns have compatible data types (at least in Oracle it doesn't work for a mix of number, date and varchar columns)

Comment: If you're checking 60 columns, index will break down very quickly anyway. Even if each column could only contain "NULL" or "1", there are 2^60 comibinations, (taking a million as 1024*1024, that's 1 million million million combinations) Creating and maintaining that index would be a significant overheard.  A computed column or materialised view is the only practical performance tuning (imho)

Comment: That;s why DBAs tune the databases - that's not a one-shot operation, it should be done (or at least checked) frequently. I wouldn't have 60 indexes, I'd be examining RUNSTATS output and table content to see where things could be improved, and then adjusting the indexes to squeeze out maximum grunt.

Answer (score 8):

```
where c1 is null and c2 is null ... and c60 is null
```

shortcut using **`string concatenation`** (Oracle syntax):

```
where c1||c2||c3 ... c59||c60 is null
```

Comment: That last bit unfortunately relies on the braindead Oracle inability to tell the difference between an empty string and NULL. It is not a good solution.

Comment: But I'm going to vote you up as the first bit is the right way to do it, sans any possibility of refactoring the DB table.

Comment: And when you use vendor-specific functionality, that vendor gets a grip on your short-and-curlies :-)

Comment: If you DON'T use vendor specific functionality, you still DON'T get portability.  No main stream RDBMS that I know of correctly implements ANSI SQL (of any ANSI SQL standard).  Besides performance tuning, security design, etc, etc should be based on the exact platform you're on (imho).  It's an imperfect world, so I don't try to pretend otherwise...

Comment: If you're going to make blanket assertions @Dems, at least back them up with hard data :-). Even if what you say were true, your comment that you don't get portability is correct only if your code tries to use EVERY feature of SQL. Using an intelligent subset will make it portable everywhere and avoid lock-in. If you're happy with staying with DB2 or MSSQL or MySQL, that's fine, use all the speed-up features you want. But we design for portability because that's what our clients want.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if you have a table that has so many nulls and you use SQL Server 2008 - you might want to define the table using sparse columns (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280604.aspx).

Secondly I am not sure if coalesce solves the question asks - it seems like Ammu might actually want to find the list of columns that are null for all rows, but I might have misunderstood. Nevertheless - it is an interesting question, so I wrote a procedure to list null columns for any given table:

```
IF (OBJECT_ID(N'PrintNullColumns') IS NOT NULL)
    DROP PROC dbo.PrintNullColumns;
go
CREATE PROC dbo.PrintNullColumns(@tablename sysname)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @query nvarchar(max);
    DECLARE @column sysname;
    DECLARE columns_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT c.name
        FROM sys.tables t JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
        WHERE t.name = @tablename AND c.is_nullable = 1;
    OPEN columns_cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM columns_cursor INTO @column;
    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
        SET @query = N'
        DECLARE @c int
        SELECT @c = COUNT(*) FROM ' + @tablename + ' WHERE ' + @column + N' IS NOT NULL
        IF (@c = 0)
            PRINT (''' + @column + N''');'
        EXEC (@query);

        FETCH NEXT FROM columns_cursor INTO @column;
    END
    CLOSE columns_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE columns_cursor;
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
    RETURN;
END;
go
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to write the columns names, Try can do something like this.
This will show you all the rows when all of the columns values are null except for the columns you specified (IgnoreThisColumn1 & IgnoreThisColumn2).

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @query = ISNULL(@query+', ','') + [name] 
                FROM  sys.columns 
                WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID('yourTableName') 
                AND  [name] != 'IgnoreThisColumn1' 
                AND  [name] !=  'IgnoreThisColumn2';

SET @query = N'SELECT * FROM TmpTable WHERE COALESCE('+ @query +') IS NULL';

EXECUTE(@query)
```

Result

[image: Result One]

If you don't want rows when all the columns are null except for the columns you specified, you can simply use `IS NOT NULL` instead of `IS NULL`

```
SET @query = N'SELECT * FROM TmpTable WHERE COALESCE('+ @query +') IS NOT NULL';
```

Result

[[image: Result Two[2]]

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to find out if a specific set of 60 columns are null, or do you just want to find out if any 60 out of the 100 columns are null (not necessarily the same 60 for each row?)

If it is the latter, one way to do it in oracle would be to use the nvl2 function, like so:

```
select ... where (nvl2(col1,0,1)+nvl2(col2,0,1)+...+nvl2(col100,0,1) > 59)
```

A quick test of this idea:

```
select 'dummy' from dual where nvl2('somevalue',0,1) + nvl2(null,0,1) > 1
```

Returns 0 rows while:

```
select 'dummy' from dual where nvl2(null,0,1) + nvl2(null,0,1) > 1
```

Returns 1 row as expected since more than one of the columns are null.

Answer (score 0):

It would help to know which db you are using and perhaps which language or db framework if using one.

This should work though on any database.

Something like this would probably be a good stored procedure, since there are no input parameters for it.

```
select count(*) from table where col1 is null or col2 is null ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another method that seems to me to be logical as well (use Netezza or TSQL)

```
SELECT KeyColumn, MAX(NVL2(TEST_COLUMN,1,0) AS TEST_COLUMN 
  FROM TABLE1
 GROUP BY KeyColumn
```

So every `TEST_COLUMN` that has `MAX` value of 0 is a column that contains all nulls for the record set. The function `NVL2` is saying if the column data is not null return a 1, but if it is null then return a 0.

Taking the `MAX` of that column will reveal if any of the rows are not null. A value of 1 means that there is at least 1 row that has data. Zero (0) means that each row is null.

Answer (score 0):

I use the below query when i have to check for multiple columns NULL. I hope this is helpful . If the SUM comes to a value other than Zero , then you have NULL in that column

```
select SUM (CASE WHEN col1 is null then 1 else 0 end) as null_col1,
SUM (CASE WHEN col2 is null then 1 else 0 end) as null_col2,
SUM (CASE WHEN col3 is null then 1 else 0 end) as null_col3, ....
.
.
.
from tablename
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use

```
select NUM_NULLS  , COLUMN_NAME  from all_tab_cols  where table_name = 'ABC' and COLUMN_NAME in ('PQR','XYZ');
```

Comment: Good answers include some kind of [explainment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) why it works.. This post was marked as a [low quality](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/22409526) ..