# How do I return the column name in table where a null value exists?

Tags: sql

I have a table of more than 2 million rows and over 100 columns. I need to run a query that checks if there are any null values in any row or column of the table and return an ID number where there is a null. I've thought about doing the following, but I was wondering if there is a more concise way of checking this?

```
SELECT [ID]
from [TABLE_NAME]
where
   [COLUMN_1] is null
or [COLUMN_2] is null
or [COLUMN_3] is null or etc.
```

Comment: best way is: don't create such big tables

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? SQL Server?

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: This has been asked a couple of times. See this answer (and linked duplicate) at dba.stackexchange: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/20398/2397

Comment: It doesn't matter how concise you can get it: all 2 million rows will be scanned with an OR anyway

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Query to check if 40 columns in table is null](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780337/sql-query-to-check-if-40-columns-in-table-is-null)

Comment: Sorry if it is a duplicate. I searched and didn't find anything that I thought would help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your method is fine.  If your challenge is writing out the `where` statement, then you can run a query like this:

```
select column_name+' is null or '
from information_schema.columns c
where c.table_name = 'table_name'
```

Then copy the results into a query window and use them for building the query.

I used SQL Server syntax for the query, because it looks like you are using SQL Server.  Most databases support the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables, but the syntax for string concatenation varies among databases.  Remember to remove the final `or` at the end of the last comparison.

You can also copy the column list into Excel and use Excel formulas to create the list.

Comment: This is clever. I knew about information_schema, but I never thought to concate onto the end of the column names. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use something similar to the following:

```
declare @T table
(
  ID int,
  Name varchar(10),
  Age int,
  City varchar(10),
  Zip varchar(10)
)  

insert into @T values 
(1, 'Alex', 32, 'Miami', NULL),
(2,  NULL,  24,  NULL,   NULL)

;with xmlnamespaces('http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' as ns)
select ID,
       (
          select *
          from @T as T2
          where T1.ID = T2.ID
          for xml path('row'), elements xsinil, type 
       ).value('count(/row/*[@ns:nil = "true"])', 'int') as NullCount
from @T as T1
```