# SQL select distinct exclude NULL rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause, sql-null

SQL query:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT [File Version Number], [Enrollment Employee ID] 
FROM Participant
```

Result:

```sql
+---------------------+------------------------+
| Fule Version Number | Enrollment Employee ID |
+---------------------+------------------------+
| null                | null                   |
| null                | 1100527                |
| null                | 5032506                |
| v2.2.0              | null                   |
+---------------------+------------------------+
```

Desired result: exclude rows with NULL data; the FIRST row.

I understand we can use where clause on both columns to filter null rows but what if we have large number of columns to select, and we don't want to have long `where` clause?

Any solution or workaround would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: If you could `coalesce` the various columns, i.e. there is some compatible data type, and the result `is null` then they're all `null`.

Comment: Can you use `dynamic sql`? check if this could help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780337/sql-query-to-check-if-40-columns-in-table-is-null#answer-49907544

Comment: A `WHERE` is exactly what you want here.

Comment: What SGBDR do you use?

Comment: If only the first row, "WHERE [Enrollment Employee ID] IS NOT NULL OR [File Version Number] IS NOT NULL"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exclude rows where all values are `NULL`, then a `WHERE` clause is what you need:

```
Select Distinct [File Version Number], [Enrollment Employee ID] 
From Participant
where [File Version Number] is not null or [Enrollment Employee ID] is not null;
```

If your concern is *writing* the query, then you can facilitate that by using the metadata tables for your database.  You can query the "columns" metadata to construct the `where` clause -- either using SQL or a spreadsheet or some other tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to do that in pure SQL (without dynamic SQL), then, one way or another, you will need to enumerate the column names.

The basic solution is to use `or` conditions:

```
where col1 is not null or col2 is not null ... or coln is not null;
```

You could also use `coalesce()` - as commened by HABO:

```
where coalesce(col, col2, ..., coln) is not null
```

`concat_ws()` also comes to mind - that's the same logic as `coalesce()` really:

```
where concat_ws(col1, col2, ..., coln) is not null
```

Finally, we could also use `cross apply` to unpivot, then aggregate:

```
select ...
from participant p
cross apply (
    select count(col) cnt
    from (values (p.col1), (p.col2), ..., (p.coln)) x(col)
) x
where cnt > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try to use an INNER JOIN, e.g.:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [File Version Number], [Enrollment Employee ID] 
FROM Participant AS p1
INNER JOIN Participant AS p2 ON p1.[Enrollment Employee ID] = p2.[Enrollment Employee ID]
WHERE FileVersionNumber IS NOT NULL AND EnrollmentEmployeeID IS NOT NULL;
```

but in this case you have woud have to join any every field that possibly could contain a NULL value.

So I suggest you still should add a where statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [File Version Number], [Enrollment Employee ID] 
FROM Participant
WHERE FileVersionNumber IS NOT NULL AND EnrollmentEmployeeID IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: The `inner join` would, by not being an `outer join`, exclude the rows where the `join` condition is null, hence no need to add a `where` clause as long and every column is joined to itself. A single `inner join` is sufficient since all of the columns can be lumped into one `on` clause. How that improves on a `where` clause, other than by being unclear, is unclear.